# How can I use a Wildcard in a key val within Jquery's if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking through and found plenty of sources on using wildcards within the selectors & operators, such as [id*='owner'] and such but I feel like I have a more 'unique' spot.  I am trying to get a field to hide if someone with a particular "label" is logged in.  The jquery is setup to fetch that label for me through a JSON query and then stores them with a count.
jso

```
Object { 1="Manager", 2="CSR", 3="Owner - CSR"}
```

And here is the full jquery statement:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var KBOXUSER = '';
$j(document) .ready(function () {
    //Get logged in User
    KBOXUSER = $j('*:contains("User: "):last') .text();
    var n1 = KBOXUSER.indexOf('User: ') + 6;
    var n2 = KBOXUSER.indexOf('Organization:');
    KBOXUSER = KBOXUSER.substring(n1, n2);
    $j.getJSON('/common/jkuery.php?id=104&query_type=sqlp&p1=' + KBOXUSER + '', function (data) {
        $j.each(data.json, function(key, val) {
            if (val != 'IT Department' && val != 'Owner - *') {
            $j("#ticket_form.edit table tbody tr td:contains('Status:')").hide();
            $j('#fields\\[status_id\\]').hide();
            };
        });     
    });
});
```

So I want it to find people that AREN'T IT Department and hide these, as well as people are AREN'T Owner-* (which could be Owner - CSR, Owner A/P, so on).  I've run into a problem with both the operator && and || as both provide different results.  I use the OR || just fine in another query which reduces selections in a drop down but that doesn't seem to work here.

Side-note - Even setting the above to a static item such as "Owner - CSR" I'm not getting the results proper-like and I believe it's because of where it is in the thread.  If need be, I can change the jquery statement to order OWNER - * first if that what it takes...

I would even be satisfied if I just had a run on of operators if there is no wildcard available such as:

```
if (val != 'IT Department' && val != 'Owner - CSR' && val != 'Owner - Warehouse) {
```

but that doesn't seem to be working with these operators..

HELP! :)

Comment: When you compare strings, as in `'this' != 'this'` there are no wildcards, it's just strings, so they have to match **exactly**, not even a space off, or it won't work.

Comment: So you're saying I can't wildcard it within the string, I'm just going to have to write out each of my possible matches?  Understood, and I can live with that.  What I can't live with is the operators not 'working' as I would like them too.  Let's call that "Part 2" of the issue.

Comment: I'm saying you can't use wildcards, as in `*` inside strings like that, you can however use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or regex to partially match a string in just about any possible way.